# Laravel optimize

Tags: laravel, php

Laravel optimize, как загнать контроллер туда? При попытках пишет про миксед неймспейсы. Если добавить неймспейсы, то при попытке загрузиться пишется, что контроллер редекларируется (т.е. он грузит из компилед и грузит из папки контроллеров).

**Обновление**

Есть некоторое веб-приложение, у него есть контроллеры. Грузится оно крайне медленно - около секунды. Я добавляю в app/config/compile.php мои контроллеры, они, собственно, компилируются, так скажем, но все перестает работать.

Comment: я не понял \_ничего\_

Comment: Laravel optimize, но не как не Laravel optimaze :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А контроллеры у вас как объявляются? Где они лежат?
И вообще - у Вас задача засунуть все контроллеры в compiled? У Вас там вся логика? По хорошему, в compile нужно класть файлы, которые продёргиваются за один запрос несколько раз. Иначе - экономия на спичках.

И да - медленно работает где? На продуктивном сервере или разработческом (homestaed)? Что является бутылочным горлышком - выясняли?

Comment: У меня была такая особая система, зарефакторил. На нормальном сервакер работает, но не летает. Для сравния скорость ответа битрикса быстрее, чем Laravel (простой однастраничник), на глаз, конечно, не заметно, но как-то это странно.

Comment: Стоит делать замеры, где именно происходят самые ресурсо- и времяпожирающие действия, и пробовать оптимизировать их...